# Reset screen capture and microphone permission for all apps through terminal in macOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, macos-catalina, electron-builder

I am working on an electron app which has audio and screen recording features.

I have to ask permission for both features before moving to the signup flow.

So while developing, I manually need to go to *System Preferences* -> *Security* and *Privacy* then uncheck both permissions. It takes too much time so I have to do that thing using the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Microphone use - **tccutil reset Microphone**
For the Screen Recording use - **tccutil reset ScreenCapture**